# In Ruby, why do I need to convert an integer into a string to print it?

Tags: ruby

Help me to understand why this doesn't work:

```
puts 'What\'s your favorite number?'
number = gets.chomp
newnumber = number.to_i + 5
puts 'I think you really mean ' + newnumber + ' right?'
```

And why this one does:

```
puts 'What\'s your favorite number?'
number = gets.chomp
newnumber = number.to_i + 5
puts 'I think you really mean ' + newnumber.to_s + ' right?'
```

I don't understand why I have to convert the "newnumber" integer into a string. Shouldn't it just print into a string automatically?

Also ... if this works

```
puts 'What\'s your favorite number?'
number = gets.chomp
puts number.to_i + 5
```

Why can't I just do this?

```
puts 'What\'s your favorite number?'
number = gets.chomp
puts 'I think you really mean ' + number.to_i + 5 + ' right?'
```

Comment: BTW, in case it wasn't clear, my program goal was to simply ask for some number input, then modify the number, then print back the modified number.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you mean by 'works'.  What output did you expect, and what did you actually see?

Comment: Because different languages have different philosophies on how things should work.

Comment: One thing to note is that Ruby tends to prefer string interpolation using double quotes. You can do "hello world #{newnumber}" and it will  convert the value to a string.

Comment: you can also do the following "What's your favorite number?", note you no longer have to escape the single quote.

Comment: Phrasing this question as "why" rather than "how do I" makes it not a very good fit for Stack Overflow. I've solved your problem in my answer below, but I haven't actually answered the question. Consider rephrasing it as "how do I" if any of the answers below satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll look at rephrasing the question. Total newbie question I know, but I got stuck on an entry level tutorial and needed some help. In the future I'll work on modifying my questions to be more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` and `puts` do not require you to convert a number to a string. In this case, the problem is that you're trying to add a number to a string. This expression:

```
'I think you really mean ' + newnumber + ' right?'
```

has to be evaluated before `puts` can receive its argument. You can't add numbers to strings, for the reason stated in the error you'll get when you try:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

You can do this, though:

```
puts newnumber
```

If you want to get implicit type conversion while outputting, use interpolation:

```
puts "I think you really mean #{newnumber} right?"
```

Ruby will call `to_s` on `newnumber` automatically.

Note that you must use `"` double-quotes `"` around your string, because interpolation won't occur in single-quoted strings.

Comment: You can also use `printf`, which has format strings comparable to C:  `printf "I think you really mean %d, right?\n", newnumber`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but thinks that problem in concat. When you try to do:

**number.to_i + 5**

Ruby just calculate a sum of 2 integers and print out.

When you try to do:

**'I think you really mean ' + number.to_i + 5 + ' right?'**

You force the ruby interpretator to calculate a SUM of string and integers, and ruby doesn't know how to calculate it.

Also when you try to do:

**'I think you really mean ' + newnumber.to_s + ' right?'**

ERB just concat this strings.

And yes, sorry for my poor English. :)

Answer (score 0):

`puts` can accept both integer or string parameters, and even both at once:

```
puts "hello number ", 4
# hello number
# 4
```

`+` and its various overloads can accept a string + string (concatenation) or a number + number (addition) but ruby does not have an overloaded version which accepts a string + number. Yes, many other languages do (like JavaScript, etc.) but ruby has chosen not to.

This should address every case in your question; if it doesn't please let me know if something can be clarified.